# python find and replace new lines

Tags: python, replace, notepad++, newline

I have the below text:

```
Name:John
Age:23
Status:Single
Gender:Male
Name:Merry
Age:19
Gender:Female
Name:Alex
Age:20
Status:Single
Gender:Male
```

I used the below notepad++ find and replace

```
Find:\r\nAge:
Replace:!Age;
Find:\r\nStatus:
Replace:!Status;
Find:\r\nGender:
Replace:!Gender;
```

to have the output:

```
Name:John!Age;23!Status;Single!Gender;Male
Name:Merry!Age;19!Gender;Female
Name:Alex!Age;20!Status;Single!Gender;Male
```

How to do this using notepad++ python script instead of find and replace

Can I use the below statement for lines joining with some edits??

```
editor.pyreplace(r"\r$\n", "!", 0, Editor.INCLUDELINEENDINGS)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outhandle, open('file.txt', 'r') as inhandle:
        outhandle.write(inhandle.read().replace('\nAge:','!Age;').replace('\nStatus:','!Status;').replace('\nGender:','!Gender;'))
```

Output will be written to outfile.txt and considered input file as 'file.txt'.

Comment: i don't want to specify the file name . is it possible with script to be run directly on the file

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to do a single regex replace, searching for

```
\r\n(?!Name)
```

and replacing all matches with `!`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your easiest option is to replace all carriage/new-line occurences not preceeded by `Name` with an exclamation mark:

```
import re
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    print re.sub('\r?\n(?!Name)', '!', f.read())
```

Output:

```
Name:John!Age:23!Status:Single!Gender:Male
Name:Merry!Age:19!Gender:Female
Name:Alex!Age:20!Status:Single!Gender:Male
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax